# How does a browser choose which style sheet to use

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have this simple HTML page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/styleA.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/styleB.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/styleC.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='myDivClass'>Hello World!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are three style sheets. Lets say these style sheets look like so:

**styleA.css**

```
.myDivClass{
    background-color:red;
    color:black;
}
```

**styleB.css**

```
.myDivClass{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

**styleC.css**

```
.myDivClass{
     background-color:green;
}
```

As you can see they all apply a style to myDivClass in some way. How does the browser pick which style sheet is more important in terms of applying its style?

Comment: it's called "Cascading" style sheets for a reason...http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/9459062/in-which-order-do-css-stylesheets-override.  There is a link to the spec with all the info you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all your rules in all stylesheets have the same *specificity*, the one defined last wins when there are concurring definitions. So your `div.myDivClass` will have white text on green background.

This might help you **[understand *specificity*](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)**.

Answer (score 2):

See section 6.4.1 *Cascading Order* 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Basically, the more specific should win, but in your case, the selectors are identical, therefore, rule 4 applies, in which the last specified declaration wins.

Answer (score 1):

It goes in order. The "C" in CSS stands for "Cascading" meaning that the browser starts at the top and works it's way down. Whichever style is defined last is the one used.

Comment: If they're the same definitions, yes, but this can be affected by variances in specificity (ID beats class, `!important` etc.).

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, you're right, given that OP's example shares the same class though, I went with that.